# How do I echo a variable thats a double, but only show the decimal places if they're needed?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some double fields in my database and when echoing the fields out in my php I get `.00` at the end of the values.

How do I get the `.00` not to display, but display if there is a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) to remove the ".00" from the values.

```
$value = 10.00;
echo str_replace('.00', '', $value); // 10

$value = 10.52;
echo str_replace('.00', '', $value); // 10.52
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo (int)$double;
```

will simply strip off the decimal places. if you merely want to hide 'zero' decimals (10.00 -> 10), but leave non-zero decimals (10.1 -> 10.1), then you'd need to do some processing:

```
echo preg_replace('/\.0+$/', '', $double);
```

which would handle any number of zeroes after the decimal place, but leave non-zeroes in place.

Comment: `round()` seems to do this natively.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (fmod($number, 1) == 0)
{
    $number = intval($number);
}

else
{
    $number = round($number, 2);
}
```

Or just use `round()` [@ [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/xHxmz)]:

```
var_dump(round($number = 5.00, 2)); // 5
var_dump(round($number = 5.01, 2)); // 5.01
```

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrary number of `0`s at the end of the number:

```
$number = rtrim($number,".0");
```

Examples:

```
Input : 1.00
Result: 1

Input : 1.25
Result: 1.25

Input : 1.40
Result: 1.4

Input : 1.234910120000
Result: 1.23491012
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select number,if(number % 1 = 0,cast(number as unsigned),number) 
from table
```